# Find a bijection that best preserves distances

Tags: algorithm, math, machine-learning, linear-algebra

I have two spaces (not necessarily equal in dimension) with N points.
I am trying to find a bijection (pairing) of the points, such that the distances are preserved as well as possible.

I can't seem to find a discussion of possible solutions or algorithms to this question online. Can anyone suggest keywords that I could search for? Does this problem have a name, or does it come up in any domain?

Comment: There is also a `homework` tag, and there is no shame to use it...

Comment: Please clarify _such that the distances are preserved **as well as possible**_

Comment: You might try http://mathoverflow.net/ as well.

Comment: You might try "optimal transportation" as keywords, or "monge-kantorovitch problem". Although it seems not directly related to your problem, this may help you to state it precisely.

Comment: I didn't define the "distances are preserved as well as possible" part because I don't actually have a definition in my mind. I had a vague idea of what I wanted, and just needed to explore the associated literature. (just lacked the keywords to google for).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a [Multidimensional Scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling) algorithm where you are minimizing the total change in distance. Unfortunately, I have very little experience in this area and can't be of much more help.

Comment: damn. You nailed it right on its head, and from a pretty terse description. If you would have said 'SMACOF' that would probably been enough to give the solution. Anyway, +1 from me.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for. MDS is the keyword I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of the exact same problem. There are two similar types of problems:

1. Non-linear dimensionality reduction, you're given N high dimensional points and you want to find N low dimensional points that preserve distance as well as possible. MDS, mentioned by Michael Koval is one such method.
2. This might be more promising: algorithms for the assignment problem. For example Kuhn-Munkres (the Hungarian algorithm), you're given an NxN matrix that encodes the cost of matching pi with pj and you want to find the minimum cost bijection. There are many generalizations of this problem, for example b-matching (Kuhn-Munkres solves 1-matching).

Depending on how you define "preserves distances as well as possible" I think you either want (2) or a generalization of (2) in such a way that the cost doesn't only depend on the two points being matched but the assignment of all other points.

Finally, Kuhn-Munkres comes up everywhere in operations research.

Comment: Thanks, 1. is actually closer to what I was looking for, I think. It's funny though because in my case, I have N low dimensional points that I need to project to N high dimensional points :) Reverse of what usually you use MDS for. Anyway, thank you!